# Get nodes positions in a randomly generated graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, scikit-image

l have generated a random graph using NetworkX library. Now, l would like to get the (x,y) coordinates of each node.

**What l have tried ?**

```
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import random as random
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

G = nx.balanced_tree(3,3)

node_positions = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

**What l got  ?**

```
node_positions
Out[56]: 
{0: array([ 0.50797246,  0.47719004]),
 1: array([ 0.4737295 ,  0.80685253]),
 2: array([ 0.61668036,  0.5967835 ]),
 3: array([ 0.45314193,  0.18113052]),
 4: array([ 0.74582   ,  0.88535594]),
 5: array([ 0.28304618,  0.73784419]),
 6: array([ 0.22814727,  0.91634686]),
 7: array([ 0.90767018,  0.55866571]),
 8: array([ 0.22321579,  0.57663404]),
 9: array([ 0.82803591,  0.73905281]),
 10: array([ 0.15093966,  0.24096575]),
 11: array([ 0.41389402,  0.01848409]),
 12: array([ 0.74298423,  0.10585789]),
 13: array([ 0.95692361,  0.70135218]),
 14: array([ 0.9333499 ,  0.77529735]),
 15: array([ 0.59008687,  0.99666832]),
 16: array([ 0.40042269,  0.97903855]),
 17: array([ 0.12273361,  0.54150101]),
 18: array([ 0.21783263,  0.46879425]),
 19: array([ 0.1477097 ,  0.86215834]),
 20: array([ 0.31065064,  0.9689898 ]),
 21: array([ 0.0734333 ,  0.75194536]),
 22: array([ 0.97066494,  0.34137316]),
 23: array([ 0.8496917 ,  0.86787867]),
 24: array([ 1.        ,  0.43286285]),
 25: array([ 0.        ,  0.48385456]),
 26: array([ 0.12788817,  0.75838036]),
 27: array([ 0.0137882 ,  0.39184635]),
 28: array([ 0.99627758,  0.57863309]),
 29: array([ 0.89164448,  0.82786694]),
 30: array([ 0.71802896,  0.9607354 ]),
 31: array([ 0.18064846,  0.12315356]),
 32: array([ 0.00104408,  0.53985017]),
 33: array([ 0.0779511 ,  0.23378722]),
 34: array([ 0.58219827,  0.01923722]),
 35: array([ 0.30061834,  0.04107663]),
 36: array([ 0.49707994,  0.        ]),
 37: array([ 0.69939259,  0.04731438]),
 38: array([ 0.84674553,  0.13220172]),
 39: array([ 0.87227266,  0.21870199])}
```

**What l'm looking for  ?**

(x,y) spatial coordinates  for instance {0: array([ 15.5,  38])} such that x_coord is 15.5 and y_coord is 38.

however, l can't understand `{0: array([ 0.50797246,  0.47719004])}`
does it mean that `x_coord=0.50797246` and `y_coord=0.47719004` ?

if it's the case it means that all the nodes of the grahes are in the same node since the max here is 1 !!

l'm looking for integer coordinates like in skimage :

```
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=150, compactness=0.01, sigma=1)
segments_slic=segments_slic +1
regions = regionprops(segments_slic)
```

if we want to get the coordinates (x,y) we just need to make `regions[0].coords`
then we get :

```
regions[0].coords
array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 0,  2],
       ..., 
       [27, 46],
       [27, 47],
       [27, 48]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `nx.spring_layout` docs [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx-drawing-layout-spring-layout), look for the `scale` and `k` parameters:

> scale (number (default: 1)) – Scale factor for positions. Not used unless fixed is None.

---

> k (float (default=None)) – Optimal distance between nodes. If None the distance is set to 1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes. Increase this value to move nodes farther apart.

As to getting integer coordinates, you can easily do this with `int`.

```
positions = { node: (int(pos[0]),int(pos[1])) for node,pos in node_positions.items() }
```

[Edit]
`k` is the parameter for Fruchterman-Reingold layout algorithm, it is kind of strength of repulsion between nodes.
I'd better show what it does (the same graph layed out with different k's):

**k=0.001**

[image: k=0.001]

**k=0.1**

[image: k=0.1]

Comment: ThANK YOU,  it works . But l don't understand the utility and the way we initialize k

Comment: You mean `node_positions = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.15, scale=100)`?   Or it's something else you're asking?

Comment: Yes, there is what l'm asking for

Comment: What k=0.15 does ?

Comment: awesome. Thank you a lot

Comment: @ wolfrevokcats have you ever encountered this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432683/coloring-nodes-with-rgb-pixel-values-in-networkx-draw-valueerror-c-of-shape

Comment: @ericlardon I looked at your question and commented there.