# Coloring nodes with RGB pixel values in networkX.draw() : ValueError: c of shape (16, 3) not acceptable as a color sequence

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, drawing, draw, networkx

l randomly generated a graph of 16 nodes. Each nodes take a clor : red,blue or green.

Here is my code :

```
G= nx.watts_strogatz_graph(16, 2, 0, seed=seed) 
color = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
x = G.nodes()
l = len(x)
color_gen = choices(color, k=l)
node_positions = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=100)
nx.draw(G, pos=node_positions, node_color=color_gen, with_labels=True)
```

such that `color_gen` represents the color of each node :

```
['red',
 'blue',
 'blue',
 'red',
 'green',
 'blue',
 'green',
 'blue',
 'red',
 'green',
 'red',
 'blue',
 'red',
 'green',
 'green',
 'green']
```

Now l would like to change the intensity of each color given the original color. Hence l defined 3 vectors of different intensities for each RGB color as follow :

```
pixel_red_color=[[255,160,122],[250,128,114],[233,150,122],[240,128,128],[205,92,92],[220,20,60],[178,34,34],[139,0,0],
                 [128,0,0],[255,99,71],[255,69,0]]
pixel_green_color=[[124,252,0],[127,255,0],[50,205,50],[34,139,34],[0,128,0],[0,100,0],[173,255,47],
                   [154,205,50],[0,255,127],[0,250,154],[144,238,144],[107,142,35],[46,139,87]]
blue_pixel_color=[[176,224,230],[173,216,230],[135,206,250],[135,206,235],[0,191,255],[30,144,255],[100,149,237],[70,130,180],[95,158,160],
                  [65,105,225],[0,0,205],[0,0,139],[0,0,128],[25,25,112]]
```

and l updated the color of each node as follow :

```
for v in G.nodes():

    if color_gen=='red':
        c = choices(pixel_red_color, k=1)

        color_gen[v] = c[0] # c[0] in order to return [255,2,115] rathet than [[255,2,115]]

    elif color_gen=='green':
        c = choices(pixel_green_color, k=1)
        color_gen[v] = c[0]
    else :
        c= choices(blue_pixel_color, k=1)
        color_gen[v]=c[0]
```

Then, `color_gen` becomes :

olor_gen
Out[22]:

```
[[70, 130, 180],
 [135, 206, 250],
 [65, 105, 225],
 [95, 158, 160],
 [0, 0, 139],
 [176, 224, 230],
 [25, 25, 112],
 [0, 0, 205],
 [135, 206, 250],
 [65, 105, 225],
 [0, 0, 139],
 [70, 130, 180],
 [70, 130, 180],
 [70, 130, 180],
 [100, 149, 237],
 [0, 191, 255]]
```

**What l get when l feed nx.draw() with pixel_values of colors ?**

nx.draw(G,pos=node_positions, node_color=color_gen, with_labels=True)

l get the following error :

```
    raise ValueError(msg.format(c.shape, x.size, y.size))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

**What l have tried ?**

```
color_gen=np.asarray(color_gen)
```

then try again  :

```
nx.draw(G,pos=node_positions, node_color=color_gen, with_labels=True)
```

l get the following error :

```
python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3988, in scatter
    raise ValueError(msg.format(c.shape, x.size, y.size))
ValueError: c of shape (16, 3) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 16, y with size 16
```

Comment: `networkx` uses matplotlib's [color designations](https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html#specifying-colors).  The problem with your code is that matplotlib does not expect color components to be out of 0..1 range.  You have to convert RGB values into one of acceptable formats, for example:     `node_color=[ '#%02x%02x%02x' % (c[0],c[1],c[2]) for c in color_gen ]
`

Comment: what is '#%02x%02x%02x' ?

Comment: `%` is Python's [string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). Here it will produce a hex string representing a RGB value, like `#AF0D0F`.  You'd better read some python tutorial, those are very basic things.